# Extbase / type problem after update from TYPO3 7 to TYPO3 9 LTS

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I have an old extbase extension that needs to be fixed after updating from 7.6 to TYPO3 9.5.8:

This line seems to be the problem:

```
$this->registerArgument('background', FileReference::class . '|boolean', 'Image');
```

The error I get is

*The argument "background" was registered with type "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference|boolean", but is of type "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference" in view helper*

However, if I remove the |boolean I get a new error, this time

*The argument "background" was registered with type "TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference", but is of type "boolean" in view helper*

So I am kind of in a loop here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by turning the type to "string". Still not sure why It sent me in a loop before...

Answer (score 0):

I found the function in typo3_src/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/ViewHelper/AbstractViewHelper

```
/**
 * Register a new argument. Call this method from your ViewHelper subclass
 * inside the initializeArguments() method.
 *
 * @param string $name Name of the argument
 * @param string $type Type of the argument
 * @param string $description Description of the argument
 * @param boolean $required If TRUE, argument is required. Defaults to FALSE.
 * @param mixed $defaultValue Default value of argument
 * @return \TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper $this, to allow chaining.
 * @throws Exception
 * @api
 */
protected function registerArgument($name, $type, $description, $required = false, $defaultValue = null)
{
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->argumentDefinitions)) {
        throw new Exception(
            'Argument "' . $name . '" has already been defined, thus it should not be defined again.',
            1253036401
        );
    }
    $this->argumentDefinitions[$name] = new ArgumentDefinition($name, $type, $description, $required, $defaultValue);
    return $this;
}
```

So I think you have to use

```
$this->registerArgument('background', TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference, 'Image');
```